# Does the older Xbox 360 Elite support XNA 4?

Tags: xna, xbox360

Can I develop an XNA 4.0 game for the older Xbox 360 Elite? Or would I need a newer Slim model?

Comment: The new Xbox 360 4g slim does not support XNA development without a harddrive.

Comment: I believe the new Xbox 360 S models also use a different drive bay, so if you buy the 4G you'll have to buy the new 250GB drive to develop using XNA, and not one of the older, cheaper ones.

Comment: However, XNA games will _run_ just fine on models without hard drives (assuming you have some other kind of storage). You just can't do development deployments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The development platform for all Xbox 360 models is identical - that's the nice aspect of developing on consoles. The models differ in mostly incidental things like disc drive speed, number of cooling fans, and hard drive size.

The speed of the hard drive and disc drive are the only things that even remotely affect game quality / technical requirement compliance, and unless you're streaming lots of data, they're unlikely to matter for you.

Comment: But will it support the full XNA 4.0 API?

Comment: Yes. They're identical. (Technically, it doesn't support the full API - no Xbox 360 does, since the consumer OS doesn't accept mice, for example - but it won't support any less than other Xboxes.)

Answer (score 6):

Any Xbox 360 will do, regardless if old or new since they are essentially all the same in terms of CPU/RAM/GPU.